# HttpContext.User.Claims and IHttpContextAccessor both returns empty value after successful login

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

HttpContext.User.Claims and IHttpContextAccessor both returns empty value after successful login in .NET Core 2.2
Here my Startup Services,

```
  services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
              options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")
                     ,b=>b.MigrationsAssembly("AdaptiveBizapp")));

            services.AddDbContext<Project_Cost_Management_SystemContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Project_Cost_Management_SystemContext") 
                    , b => b.MigrationsAssembly("AdaptiveBizapp")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
                .AddRoles<ApplicationRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                 .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

            });
            services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/login";
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;                
                });
            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                // Set a short timeout for easy testing.
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                // Make the session cookie essential
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
 services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

and my Configure section,

```
 app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy(); 

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseAuthentication(); 
            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                routes.MapRoute(
             name: "area",
             template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
```

[image]

I used Identity and Role based authorization. After login successful, in HomeController when i read user claims or NameIdentifier is empty. But when i read in same LoginController It has value at ClaimPrincipal,

```
  public async override Task<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var principal =await base.CreateAsync(user);

            // Add your claims here
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).
               AddClaims(new[] {
         new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
            user.UserName.ToString()) 
            });


            return principal;
        }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You sure the cookie is set up correctly and your browser isn't blocking cookie for some reason? If the cookie isn't set, then its not submited on the subsequent requests and the user won't be treated as not logged in, as you can see in your first screenshot with `IsAuthenticated = false`

Comment: i have 451 role for logged user. Is any restriction on claim size? my browser not blocking cookie. i have the code as it above. Currently migrating MVC5 to Core 2.2

Comment: But if you in your browser, is the cookie set or not? Not sure if the claims are stored in the cookie (they shouldn't, but don't rely on it). Cookie size limitation however is somewhere around 4kb for most applications/browsers

Comment: I attached my browser cookie above. I enable cookie set at services config (see at top). I worry about order of service include.

Comment: cookie created as Applictionc1 to ApplicationC9 @Tseng

Comment: Running out if ideas, but bit weird you get so many cookies. Maybe they are from different applications which all run locally (in your dev environment) on the same host/port (localhost)? basically 4k is the limit on what cookies can be submitted, whether it be 1 4k cookie, 2 2k cookies or 4 1k cookies. Clear cookies and retry?

Comment: when i debug it always opens new window, there is no possible for cookie cache, when i get login page show no cookie, after login only i saw the those cookie. @Tseng

Comment: MVC 5 application only have 2 cookies. FYI

Comment: Unless you mark the cookies as "session cookie" it won't be deleted when you close / reopen the browser until it expires

Comment: Cookie stated expires "when the browser session ends". I also tried to delete cache. not working.

Comment: Cookie size limit is a function of the request size limit, since the cookie will be housed in the `Cookie` request header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you want use Depency Injection for IHttpContextAccessor you need to add :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
        ...
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
        ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: great !. I missed    services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); line in my code. after that its working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Searched all day and finally figured it out.  The claims are hydrated on the next call to the server.  Hopefully this post helps someone else out.  If you follow microsofts documentation you are good but just dont try to get the claims in the same call as when you set them.  Do another call and they will be hydrated.